# ALSA latency measurement

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, latency, alsa

I want to measure latency between capture frame and playback frames.
I have a system in which i am capturing the data from mic and putting it on spi and further to RF, same at receiver side capturing data via RF to spi and then speaker. I am getting approximately 2 sec delay. I have checked with the RF hardware, everything is clear. Is there any application or any logic through which i can measure the latency using whole system? The latency tool which is given by alsa is for loopback only, I mean in processor itself only. But I want to measure with SPI or RF loopback.

Comment: Most latency tools assume that capture&playback run on the same computer. Assuming that the (analog) mic and speaker do not have any latency, you could look at those two signals with an oscilloscope. Alternatively, route those two signals to the left and right channels of another capture device, and look at the captured file.

Comment: how to put that on other capture device, do u have any test code?

Comment: Thanks for reply